# Java / Scala import not working due to incorrect build path?

Tags: java, eclipse, scala, scala-ide

I'm very confused about how you import packages and their classes.  I have two scala projects with the following directory structures:

```
project1/
    src/
        main/
            scala/
                utils/
                    some_file.scala
                worksheet/
                    learning.sc
project2/
    * seemingly the same as project 1 *
```

The contents of some_file.scala:

```
package utils

class InterestingClass {
  override def toString(): String = "I should be interesting"
}
```

The contents of learning.sc:

```
package worksheet

import utils.InterestingClass

object learning {
  println("Welcome to the Scala worksheet")       //> Welcome to the Scala worksheet
  println(new InterestingClass())                 //> I should be interesting
}
```

When I created `project1/src/main/scala/`, in Eclipse I right clicked `main.scala` that was showing as a package underneath `src` and selected: `Build Path > Use As Source Folder`, and in Eclipse then "deleted" the `src` folder.  `project2` is actually a project I have downloaded as part of an online course so I guess there's some config in the `.project` file or the `.settings` folder that I need to tweak because `learning.sc` in project1 auto compiles as expected and produces the two outputs including `I should be interesting` but in `project2` it does not and the line `import utils.InterestingClass` shows the error `not found: object utils`.

I guess there's a subtle different in the build paths but I can't find it and the error message doesn't get me much further.  Any tips on how to debug import errors?  Looking at the build paths, they look correct (both have `project1/src/main/scala` or `project2/src/main/scala`).

Comment: @om-nom-nom why did you remove the import and import-error tags?  I think this question is exactly about those issues surely?  I'm less certain it's specifically about the scala-ide?  Using the command line `sbt` also presents similar but slightly different problems.

Comment: those tags are extremely vague and chances are low that users subscribed to them can resolve problem highly specific to **scala** and in particular, eclipse. You haven't told anything about sbt check, thus I *assumed* that problem might be specific to scala plugin. Or, speaking in a venn diagram terms, it may look [this](http://take.ms/TjOmc).

Comment: Hahaha, that venn is perfect.  Thanks @om-mom-mom.  Yeah I unfortunately didn't know where to progress from here but will put in the sbt info and will now start searching for hints in Scala-IDE.  Do you think it might be an incorrect build path or is that completely the wrong track?  Thanks for your time so far, much appreciated.

Comment: Suggest you use Intellij with sbt, much nicer than Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just opened it up again and now it's fine.  Must be a bug in Scala IDE build of Eclipse SDK

Build id: 3.0.4-2.11-20140520-1158-Typesafe

Answer (score 0):

If `project2` needs classes defined in `project1` you need to add it as a dependency in the settings of `project2`. You can do that by navigating to project properties/*Java Build Path* and then adding the dependency.